# Keydown event not removed from document and not registering on div element

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, domdocument, keydown

**NOTICE: The cause of the problem has been found, read the comments to the first answer.**

I have a dropdown list of things, that is hidden until the user invokes it.
It's something like this:

```
<div>
    <button></button>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        ....
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**The basic idea:**

The list becomes visible when the user presses the button shown in the code above.

I need to make the list able to be navigated by keyboard, 
i.e. if the user presses up or down while the list is open, the appropriate li will be selected (as if the mouse was hovering over it instead)

The event listener responsible for giving this functionality to the list should be attached when the list becomes visible and be removed when the list becomes hidden again.

Something like what Bitbucket does for the dropdown lists, but even simpler.

**The issue:**

I tried to attach an event listener to the ul and then on the div element, when the former had no effect, to no avail.
The code is this

ON SHOW

```
this.<ul or div element here>.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyboardNavigation.bind(this));
```

ON HIDE

```
this.<ul or div element here>.removeEventListener('keydown', this.keyboardNavigation.bind(this));
```

and the callback is like so

```
function keyboardNavigation(e) {
    console.log('foo');
}
```

**NOTE:** "this" is an object to which the div and the ul are both properties of, and the callback function is actually a method of that object.

**QUESTION 1:**
*Why is the `keydown` event not working when I attach it to either the ul itself or the parent div?*

Anyway, since these did not work, I decided to attach the listener to the document.
ON SHOW

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyboardNavigation.bind(this));
```

ON HIDE

```
document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.keyboardNavigation.bind(this));
```

Same callback.

Now, while this works, I noticed that the event listener is not removed from the document.
I later noticed that another `keydown` event listener I had attached to the document for another task, is also not removed when that task is done, while it should.

**QUESTION 2:** 
*Why are the event listeners not removed? I cannot understand what I am doing wrong, I am removing the exact same callback on the exact same event as were those that were added.*

Any help will be much appreciated.

**NOTE:**
I have tried doing it with jQuery's `.on()` and `.off()` instead, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429635/using-removeeventlistener-on-document-does-not-work), although I do not want to use jQuery, yet same thing is happening.

Comment: I think my post was super detailed, what more would you like to know/see?
It's not really easy to make this into a fiddle, as, like I said, I am operating on an object.
The code samples you see are exactly what I have written in my code.

Comment: As a developer it will be easier for me to start working on what ever is available than start to work from the scratch... other wise not many will have enough time to look at the situation.. if there is a demo of the problem you can attract many people to show interest in solving the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thoughts:

1 Is it because the DIV or UL isn't getting the keyboard events because the don't have focus? Whereas the document is always getting the bubbled events?

To test this, click in the DIV/UL and type and see if the keyboard events get triggered then.

I think binding to the document - if you want the user to be able to just start typing after clicking - is the right thing to do here.

2 Is this because you are not removing the same handler you created? You should retain a reference to the handler you create with the first bind call and pass this reference in to the remove call - otherwise you're creating another (different) handler and asking to remove that.

E.g.:

```
var f = this.keyboardNavigation.bind(this);
document.addEventListener('keydown', f);
document.removeEventListener('keydown', f);
```

Comment: 1. Thanks for letting me know that.
2. Blimey, I just found out why the event does not get removed.
What was breaking it was the fact that I was binding this

    .bind(this)

to the callback. 
Once I removed them the removeEventListener worked as intended.
Sorry for wasting your (and my) time fellows.

If you want add what I told you about 2. here, so that I can vote it as the answer; apparently I cannot answer my own question for the next 8 hours

Comment: Also, I'd like to ask you, when you said "You should retain a reference to the handler you create with the first bind call and pass this reference in to the remove call" how do I do that; retain a reference to the handler?

Comment: See edit; if you retain a reference so a specific function instance then you can add and remove listeners using that function correctly

Comment: @sync: thanks for the 2nd solution. 
`var f = this.keyboardNavigation.bind(this);`